# Conservation of linear momentum for a particular situation

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, thought-experiment

Imagine a situation in which a man is standing on a floor. The floor is free from any external force (you can imagine it like the floor is resting on another friction-less floor), though gravity acts on the man and there can be friction between the man and the floor. If the man starts running in one direction, the floor starts moving in the opposite direction to conserve the linear momentum.

But to a fixed observer outside the "floor and man" system, the entire system moves as the floor (with the man on it) moves in the direction opposite to the direction of running man. If the observer cannot see the running man (suppose if everything above the floor is curtained) then it appears as if the system gained momentum without any external force acting on it. Isn't this a violation of the law of conservation of linear momentum? Can anybody explain the situation, please?

Comment: The man is still *part* of the system, even if he's invisible to the observer.  He's still there putting work into the system, so no violations occur.

Comment: yes, the man is part of the system but wouldn't any force exerted by him be considered as an internal force ? The law of conservation of linear momentum states that if no net external  force acts on a system, it's linear momentum remains constant. pls explain

Comment: The total linear momentum remains constant; Add the man's linear momentum relative to the floor to the floor's linear momentum relative to the man and they'll sum to $0$.

Comment: The floor and the man will have  opposite, but same in magnitude, velocities with respect to each other. Since, the mass of the man may not be equal to mass of the floor, therefore , their linear momentums wrt each other may not cancel up. Though i think it will cancel up if the velocities are taken with respect to the fixed observer.

Comment: that answers my question i guess

Comment: Not the same velocities. Definitely not. The man will move faster along the floor than the floor moves along the frictionless floor beneath it.

Comment: it bothered me because it means a system maybe apparently moving without any external force unless the observer knows what's happening inside the system.

Comment: no but you said at first relative velocities of man and floor wrt each other. Yes, but if you take the floor's vel. wrt frictionless floor and man's vel. wrt the floor having friction,like you said in the next comment, then they will be diff.

Comment: No, I didn't. I said the linear momenta w.r.t. each other.

Comment: For linear momentum wrt each other , the velocities are also wrt each other, aren't it?

Comment: Sure, but the velocities aren't the same. The masses will be completely different, and so too will the momenta.

Comment: For finding the linear momentum with respect to each other, we find the rel. vel. with respect each. Isn't the magnitude of vel. of man wrt the floor equal to the magnitude of vel. of floor wrt to man? the masses being diff., the linear momenta will be diff. when calculated wrt each other. But if calculated wrt fixed observer, ouside system, they will cancel upto zero.

Comment: yes, it's okay. my problem is solved. thank you for your participation. cheer m8!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion I shall alter the problem so that the man is standing on a plank which itself rests on a frictionless floor.

The man and plank comprise an isolated system as far as horizontal forces are concerned. Any force (eg friction) between the man and plank are internal forces. If the man walks/runs in one direction, the plank moves in the other direction. Momentum is conserved, and as a result the centre of mass of this system remains in the same place.

Just because the man somehow becomes invisible to the observer does not mean that there is a violation of the Conservation of Momentum. You just have to look harder to find the missing momentum. The same problem of apparently missing momentum led to the postulation of the neutrino in 1930 by Wolfgang Pauli.

The man and the plank have equal and opposite momenta at all times, but not equal and opposite velocities. The heavier plank moves more slowly.

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion i came to at the end. thanks